# Correct way to approach splitting a trait

Tags: scala

I have 3 traits:

```
trait Worker

...

trait StringWorker extends Worker {
  def workString(): Iterator[String]
}

...

trait IntWorker extends Worker {
  def workInt(): Iterator[Int]
}
```

Some of my classes extend only `StringWorker`, while others extend both `StringWorker` and `IntWorker`

My code obtains the correct parser depending on some pattern matching like so:

```
def getCorrectWorkerProvider: () => Worker = {
  case SomeCase => getStringWorkerProvider()
  case _ => getIntWorkerProvider()
}
```

If I keep the traits the same as written above, then I'll pretty much always have to do something like this pseudocode:

```
if working with string, then getCorrectWorkerProvider().asInstanceOf[StringWorker].workString

if working with int, then getCorrectWorkerProvider().asInstanceOf[IntWorker].workInt
```

whereas if I changed the definition of the traits to something like this:

```
trait Worker {
  def workString(): Iterator[String]
  def workInt(): Iterator[Int]
}

trait StringWorker extends Worker
trait IntWorker extends Worker
```

then I would never have to use `.asInstanceOf[SomeWorker]` to invoke the correct method.
I believe the first way is more correct and intuitive as the methods are specific to a certain Worker, but the second way seems to be less of a headache.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I believe you're you're looking for is called the typeclass pattern.  [Here's an article that explains the idea](https://scalac.io/blog/typeclasses-in-scala/).  Basically the way it works is you create a function that takes a value of type `T` and an implicit parameter which is the `Worker[T]`, and then scala's implicit resolution mechanism finds the right `Worker[T]` for you.

Here's an example:

```scala
object Main {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        work("String")
        work(3)
    }

    def work[T](value: T)(implicit worker: Worker[T]) = {
        worker.work(value)
    }
}


trait Worker[T]{
    def work(t: T): Iterator[T]
}

object Worker {
    implicit val stringWorker: Worker[String] = (t: String) => Iterator(t)
    implicit val intWorker: Worker[Int] = (t: Int) => Iterator(t)
}
```